# How to select all distinct records as entities - hibernate - JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.2

I want to select all distinct records not a specific one and as an entities.

I'm using **Hibernate 5.6.15**, **JPA 2.2** and **JDK 11 LTS**

I tried to select `transid` as an Orders' entity but getting:
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.tailorfx.pojo.Orders`

```
public List<Orders> custOrder() {
    try ( Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Orders> cq = cb.createQuery(Orders.class);
        Root<Orders> root = cq.from(Orders.class);

        cq.select(root.get("transid")).distinct(true);

        return session.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
}
```

So I want to select all `distinct` *transid(s)* but as an *entities* not as `String`.
So how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes no sense. Which entity of the ones that have the same `transid` do you want? The first, or the last one? Or some other one based on an additional criteria?

You can run a query like the following and specify your "criteria" in the subquery.

```
public List<Orders> custOrder() {
    try ( Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Orders> cq = cb.createQuery(Orders.class);
        Root<Orders> root = cq.from(Orders.class);

        Subquery<Long> subquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<Orders> subRoot = subquery.from(Orders.class);
        subquery.select(cb.max(subRoot.get("id")));
        subquery.groupBy(subRoot.get("transid"));

        cq.where(cb.in(root.get("id")).value(subquery));

        return session.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
}
```